# how we can build a special string from a list?

Tags: python, list

I have a list like this:

`list=[' is ', ' the ', ' . ', ' .kda ', ...]`

I am wondering how I can change this is like the following:

1- put `|` after each `'`

2- remove all `'` except first and last

3- removing all `,`

4-remove `[` and `]` from the begging and end of the list

5- change all `.` to `\.` even if it is not alone. for example changing `u.s` to `u\.s`

output:

`list= is | the |  \. |  \.kda | ...`

Comment: I'm guessing you're trying to assemble a regex pattern?

Comment: yes exactly, I want to remove them from a big text file

Comment: Hello, I'm not sure what are you trying to accomplish.. you want to turn the list of words into a string? if so a simple `list = " ".join(list)` and then repeat just to remove double spaces

Comment: Modifying mrbTT's comment, I'd say " |".join(list), then process with a regex to replace "." with "\." ... and that turns out be be Timur Shtatland's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub)

```
import re
list = [' is ', ' the ', ' . ', ' .kda ']
s = '|'.join([re.sub(r'\.', '\.', x) for x in list])
print(s)
# is | the | \. | \.kda
```

Comment: can I also remove the first and last `'` ?

Comment: or put `r` before `'` in the beginning

Comment: @elham Not sure why you see the quotes... Perhaps you are using an IDE? When I wrap the entire chunk of code above into a python **script** and run it from the command line like so: `./script_name.py`, the output of the script has no quotes:  is | the | \. | \.kda

Comment: @elham My suggested workaround would be to run the code using a script executed from the command line, instead of Jupyter... There is no such issue there. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

String manipulation

```
answer = str(list).replace("'", "'|").replace(".", "\.").strip('[').strip(']')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list=[' is ', ' the ', ' . ', ' .kda ']
# add a r before the string declaration to specify it as a regex string
re_list = r"|".join(list).replace('.', '\.')
print(re_list)

#>>>' is | the |  \. |  \.kda | ...'
```